# Calling SQL through PHP, Select all command but is missing 1 result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, missing-data

So basically, I have a PHP webpage using SQL to check if any id is selected. If it is not, it auto selects all results with the date 2015. However the 1st result is always missing. From reading other posts, I can only assume my select all $result is starting at 1, even though the data in the table starts at 0. Either that, or somehow some part of my code is eating the first result. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])){$id=$_GET["id"];}else{$id="";}

if ($id==""){
$select ="select * from organicgrants where lastupdated > '2015'";

$result = mysql_query($select);
if (!$result) {
    echo("<P>Error performing query: " .
       mysql_error() . "</P>");
    exit();
}   
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $organicgrantsid=$row["organicgrantsid"];
    $firstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
    $lastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
    $lastupdated=date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["lastupdated"]));

    echo ("<p>");                       
    echo("<p><b>Total Applications Displayed: ".mysql_num_rows($result)."</b></p>");
    echo ("<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
    echo ("<tr bgcolor=\"#cccccc\"><td><Strong>Teacher Name</td><td><Strong>School Name</td><td><Strong>State</td><td><Strong>Grade(s)</td><td><Strong>Submitted Date</td>
    <td><Strong>Status</td></Strong></tr>");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {;
    $organicgrantsid=$row["organicgrantsid"];
    $teacherfirstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
    $teacherlastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
    $schoolname=$row["schoolname"];
    $schoolstate=$row["schoolstate"];
    $gradelevels=$row["gradelevels"];
    $lastupdated=$row["lastupdated"];
    $grantstatus=$row["grantstatus"];
    //$staffawarded=$row["staffawarded"];
    //$staffconference=$row["staffconference"];

switch ($grantstatus){
    case "":
        $grantstatus="Waiting List";
    break;
    case "0":
        $grantstatus="Waiting List";
    break;
    case "1":
        $grantstatus="Awarded";
    break;
    case "2":
        $grantstatus="Not Awarded";
    break;
}

    $lastupdated=date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["lastupdated"]));
    echo ("<tr><td><a href=\"results.php?id=".$organicgrantsid."\">".$teacherfirstname." ".$teacherlastname."</a></td><td>".$schoolname."</td><td>".$schoolstate."</td><td>".$gradelevels."</td><td>(".$lastupdated.")</td><td>".$grantstatus."</td></tr>");

}
echo ("</table>");
}
}else{

$select ="select * from organicgrants where organicgrantsid=$id";

$result = mysql_query($select);
    if (!$result) {
    echo("<P>Error performing query: " .
       mysql_error() . "</P>");
    exit();
    }   
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $schoolname=$row["schoolname"];
    $schooladdress=$row["schooladdress"];
    $schoolcity=$row["schoolcity"];
    $schoolstate=$row["schoolstate"];
    $schoolzip=$row["schoolzip"];
    $schoolphone=$row["schoolphone"];
    $schoolcounty=$row["schoolcounty"];
    $gradelevelsitem=$row["gradelevels"];
    $teacherfirstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
    $teacherlastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
    $teacherposition=$row["teacherposition"];
    $teacheremail=$row["teacheremail"];
    $teacherphone=$row["teacherphone"];
    $numberofstudents=$row["numberofstudents"];
    $budgetA=$row["budgetA"];
    $budgetB=$row["budgetB"];
    $budgetC=$row["budgetC"];
    $budgetD=$row["budgetD"];
    $budgetE=$row["budgetE"];
    $budgetF=$row["budgetF"];
    $budgetG=$row["budgetG"];
    $budgetI=$row["budgetI"];
    $budgetJ=$row["budgetJ"];
    $budgetK=$row["budgetK"];
    $budgetAamt=$row["budgetAamt"];
    $budgetBamt=$row["budgetBamt"];
    $budgetCamt=$row["budgetCamt"];
    $budgetDamt=$row["budgetDamt"];
    $budgetEamt=$row["budgetEamt"];
    $budgetFamt=$row["budgetFamt"];
    $budgetGamt=$row["budgetGamt"];
    $budgetHamt=$row["budgetHamt"];
    $budgetIamt=$row["budgetIamt"];
    $budgetJamt=$row["budgetJamt"];
    $budgetKamt=$row["budgetKamt"];
    $budgetLamt=$row["budgetLamt"];
    $budgetMamt=$row["budgetMamt"];
    $essayimportant=$row["essayimportant"];
    $essaybenefit=$row["essaybenefit"];
    $essayexperience=$row["essayexperience"];
    $essaybeneficial=$row["essaybeneficial"];
    $supportingfunds=$row["supportingfunds"];
    $principalname=$row["principalname"];
    $principalemail=$row["principalemail"];
    $grantstatus=$row["grantstatus"];
    $w9status=$row["w9status"];
    $agreementstatus=$row["agreementstatus"];
    $progressstatus=$row["progressstatus"];
    $finalstatus=$row["finalstatus"];
    $receiptsstatus=$row["receiptsstatus"];
    $staffstatus=$row["staffstatus"];
    $imisstatus=$row["imisstatus"];

    $schooladmin=$row["schooladmin"];
    if ($schooladmin==1){$schooladmin="Yes";}else{$schooladmin="No";}
    $w9form=$row["w9form"];
    if ($w9form==1){$w9form="Yes";}else{$w9form="No";}
    $gradelevelsitem="";
    if (isset($_POST['gradelevels'])==true){$gradelevels=$_POST['gradelevels'];foreach ($gradelevels as $key => $value )$gradelevelsitem.="$value, ";} 
    $gradelevelsitem=substr($gradelevelsitem,0,(strlen($gradelevelsitem)-2));`
```

Comment: You're reading a row in a `while` condition before you emit your table header. Those values are overwritten when you read further rows in a second `while` loop which presumably emits your table, although you haven't posted that code.

Comment: I'm not understanding your two WHILE statements (and not seeing the corresponding closing brackets). But it is a problem to WHILE through your results twice without resetting the record pointer.

Comment: I didn't want to overwhelm anyone who was attempting to help. The remaining code basically takes said $id and displays the results in a layout view. I I'll post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of two `while` loops (except of stealing your first `row` – in the *inner loop*  you reassign the value of the `$row`  variable from the outer loop's first iteration)? Move all your assignments/output in the first `while` loop a remove the second (you are missing curly brackets `{}` so I guess it is an inner loop).

Instead of this :

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $organicgrantsid=$row["organicgrantsid"];
    $firstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
    $lastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
    $lastupdated=date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["lastupdated"]));

    echo ("<p>");                       
    echo("<p><b>Total Applications Displayed: ".mysql_num_rows($result)."</b></p>");
    echo ("<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
    echo ("<tr bgcolor=\"#cccccc\"><td><Strong>Teacher Name</td><td><Strong>School Name</td><td><Strong>State</td><td><Strong>Grade(s)</td><td><Strong>Submitted Date</td><td><Strong>Status</td></Strong></tr>");

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {;
        $organicgrantsid=$row["organicgrantsid"];
        $teacherfirstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
        $teacherlastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
        $schoolname=$row["schoolname"];
        $schoolstate=$row["schoolstate"];
        $gradelevels=$row["gradelevels"];
        $lastupdated=$row["lastupdated"];
        $grantstatus=$row["grantstatus"];
        //$staffawarded=$row["staffawarded"];
        //$staffconference=$row["staffconference"];

        switch ($grantstatus){
        case "":
            $grantstatus="Waiting List";
        break;
        case "0":
            $grantstatus="Waiting List";
        break;
        case "1":
            $grantstatus="Awarded";
        break;
        case "2":
            $grantstatus="Not Awarded";
        break;
        }

        $lastupdated=date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["lastupdated"]));
        echo ("<tr><td><a href=\"results.php?id=".$organicgrantsid."\">".$teacherfirstname." ".$teacherlastname."</a></td><td>".$schoolname."</td><td>".$schoolstate."</td><td>".$gradelevels."</td><td>(".$lastupdated.")</td><td>".$grantstatus."</td></tr>");
    }
    echo ("</table>");
}
```

Use this :

```
echo ("<p>");                       
echo("<p><b>Total Applications Displayed: ".mysql_num_rows($result)."</b></p>");
echo ("<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
echo ("<tr bgcolor=\"#cccccc\"><td><Strong>Teacher Name</td><td><Strong>School Name</td><td><Strong>State</td><td><Strong>Grade(s)</td><td><Strong>Submitted Date</td><td><Strong>Status</td></Strong></tr>");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $organicgrantsid=$row["organicgrantsid"];
    $firstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
    $lastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
    $lastupdated=date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["lastupdated"]));
    $organicgrantsid=$row["organicgrantsid"];
    $teacherfirstname=$row["teacherfirstname"];
    $teacherlastname=$row["teacherlastname"];
    $schoolname=$row["schoolname"];
    $schoolstate=$row["schoolstate"];
    $gradelevels=$row["gradelevels"];
    $lastupdated=$row["lastupdated"];
    $grantstatus=$row["grantstatus"];
    //$staffawarded=$row["staffawarded"];
    //$staffconference=$row["staffconference"];

    switch ($grantstatus){
        case "":
            $grantstatus="Waiting List";
        break;
        case "0":
            $grantstatus="Waiting List";
        break;
        case "1":
            $grantstatus="Awarded";
        break;
        case "2":
            $grantstatus="Not Awarded";
        break;
    }

    $lastupdated=date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["lastupdated"]));
    echo ("<tr><td><a href=\"results.php?id=".$organicgrantsid."\">".$teacherfirstname." ".$teacherlastname."</a></td><td>".$schoolname."</td><td>".$schoolstate."</td><td>".$gradelevels."</td><td>(".$lastupdated.")</td><td>".$grantstatus."</td></tr>");        
}
echo ("</table>");
```

Comment: I posted the remaining code above. (Also thanks for the cleanup =p )

Comment: @JaredAquaReece : Updated the hell out of it.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you! I'll definitely be reviewing this to see how I can make improvements. I inherited this project, so I wasn't 100% clear on all the details from the beginning.